# Unable to read data from firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on android app where `Firebase` is being used for maintaining mobile back end. I have database in this format on `Firebase`

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-Kh2wjxeT-w26opA0yqe" : {
      "email" : "XX@gmail.com",
      "firstName" : "XX",
      "interest" : {
        "interests" : [ "Cricket", "Table Tennis", "Football" ]
      },
      "lastName" : "XXX",
      "password" : "abcd@1234"
    }
  }
}
```

### Users.java

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
    public String password;

    public Interest interest;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Interest interest) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.interest = interest;
    }
}
```

### Interest.java

```
public class Interest {

    public List<String> interests;

    public Interest() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public Interest(List<String> interests) {
        this.interests = interests;
    }
}
```

I have added `addValueEventListener` on child "users" in this way

```
mDatabase.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Log.d("Scheduled", user.firstName + user.lastName + user.interest.interests.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
    }
});
```

It is fetching correct data what I have on `Firebase` but it is not mapping data in `Users` java object so when I am unable to access values. I am not sure what mistake I am doing here.

> Log.d("Scheduled", user.firstName + user.lastName + user.interest.interests.toString());

Comment: In your `Interest` class, in stead of using a `List<String>` use a `Map<String, Object>`. It will work for sure. And don't forget to set, public setters and getter in your model class.

Comment: I guess problem because of created unique Id's ` "-Kh2wjxeT-w26opA0yqe" and I have nothing like that in `User.java`

Comment: @AlexM. I tried `HashMap also but it is not working

Comment: Williams, please remodel your class. Remove your `Interest` class and in `User` class create a `Map` named `interest`. And than create public setters and getters.

Comment: @AlexM. I have done https://pastebin.com/hvM8TxbK it is not working

Comment: No, you haven't done. I repet, you need to create a `Map` in your `User` class. First declare a field in `User` class: `Map<String, Object> interests`,  than create public setter and getters, in the same way you did with the others (firstName, lastName etc). When you'll create the object of `User` class, you can use the constructor or the setter method to set the `Map`. And when you'll try to `Log`, you need to use something like this: `user.getInterest` which will be a map, and than you will be able to iterate over it. Is it now clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140104/discussion-between-williams-and-alex-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display the data, you need change your code like this:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
        String firstName = dataSnapshot.child("firstName").getValue(String.class); 
        Log.d("Scheduled", firstName); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { 
    // Failed to read value 
    } 
});
```

In which `userId` is the unique id generated by the `push()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mapping the dataSnapshot to the correct java class?.

Because I see you have named your file as Users.java and when you getValue, you create object for User.

```
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

Instead should it be

```
Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
```

Just curious whether you have named it right.

And also use a Map instead of a List for the Users and it will work for sure.

`

Comment: I have `User.java`, I guess problem because of created unique Id's  ` "-Kh2wjxeT-w26opA0yqe"`

Comment: what is the difference between if I use List/Map here ?

Comment: Yeah just use a HashMap instead of List in your Interests class, so you can map the unique Id to each object